# Why atomic store on variable that cross cache-line boundaries compiles to normal MOV store instruction?

Tags: c, gcc, x86, atomic, memory-alignment

let's look on the code

```
#include <stdint.h>
#pragma pack (push,1)
typedef struct test_s
{
    uint64_t a1;
    uint64_t a2;
    uint64_t a3;
    uint64_t a4;
    uint64_t a5;
    uint64_t a6;
    uint64_t a7;
    uint8_t b1;
    uint64_t a8;
}test;

int main()
{
    test t;
    __atomic_store_n(&(t.a8), 1, __ATOMIC_RELAXED);
}
```

since we have packed structure, the a8 is not naturally aligned and also should be split between different 64 bytes cache boundaries, but the generated assembly  GCC 12.2 is

```
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     eax, 1
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-23], rax
        mov     eax, 0
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

why does it translate to simple MOV? Doesn't the MOV not atomic in that case?

Addition:
Same code on clang 16 call to atomic function and translates to

```
main:                                   # @main
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 80
        lea     rdi, [rbp - 72]
        add     rdi, 57
        mov     qword ptr [rbp - 80], 1
        mov     rsi, qword ptr [rbp - 80]
        xor     edx, edx
        call    __atomic_store_8@PLT
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 80
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Correct, the store isn't atomic in that case, misaligned atomic operations aren't supported in GNU C.**

You created a misaligned `uint64_t` and took its address. That's [not safe in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70980038/how-to-properly-access-packed-struct-members).  Packed structs only work reliably when you access their misaligned members through the struct directly.  You can also [create crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47510783/why-does-unaligned-access-to-mmaped-memory-sometimes-segfault-on-amd64) with misaligned-pointer undefined behaviour, e.g. with a packed `struct { char a; int arr[1024]; }` and then passing the pointer as a plain `int*` to a function that might auto-vectorize.

If you use `__atomic_store_n` on variables that aren't sufficiently aligned, it's undefined behaviour AFAIK.  I don't think it supports `typedef __attribute__((aligned(1), may_alias)) int *unaligned_int;` producing different asm.

[GCC's `__atomic` builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) don't have a way to query the required alignment like we can with `alignas(std::atomic_ref<uint64_t>::required_alignment) uint64_t foo;`

There is `bool __atomic_is_lock_free (size_t size, void *ptr)` which takes a pointer arg to check the alignment (`0` for typical / default alignment for the type), but it returns `1` for size=8 even with a guaranteed-cache-line-split object like the `a8` member of `_Alignas(64) test global_t;`.  (Without known alignment for the start of the struct, `a8` in a pointed-to object might happen to be fully within one cache line, which is [sufficient on Intel but not AMD for atomicity guarantees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624881/why-is-integer-assignment-on-a-naturally-aligned-variable-atomic-on-x86/36685056#36685056).)

**I think you're supposed to assume that for any lock-free atomic, it needs `alignas(sizeof(T))`, i.e. natural alignment, otherwise you can't safely use `__atomic` builtins on it.**  This isn't explicitly documented in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html but perhaps is somewhere else.

---

See also [atomic_ref when external underlying type is not aligned as requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61996108/atomic-ref-when-external-underlying-type-is-not-aligned-as-requested) re: implementation design considerations for that case, whether to check alignment and make things slow, or whether to let the user shoot themselves in the foot like you're doing, by making the access non-atomic.

GCC could detect this and warn, which would be good, but I wouldn't expect them to add compiler back-end support for x86's ability to do misaligned atomic accesses (with a `lock` prefix for an RMW instruction, or `xchg`) at the cost of extremely bad performance which locks the bus and thus slows down other cores.  That's a disaster on modern many-core servers, so nobody wants that, the right fix is to fix your code.

Most other ISAs can't do misaligned atomic operations at all.

---

Semi-related: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65146#c4 - even in non-packed structs, GCC under-aligned C11 `_Atomic` members for a long time, e.g. keeping the default alignof(uint64_t)==4 on some 32-bit ISAs like x86 `-m32`, not promoting to the necessary `alignas(sizeof(T))`.  `_Atomic uint64_t a8` doesn't change GCC's code-gen, even with direct direct for a load, and clang refused to compile it.

##### Interesting clang output

As you note, it warns, unlike GCC.   With `__attribute__((packed))` on the struct rather than `#pragma pack`, we also get warnings for taking the address at all.  ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1AB9U8lJL6yAngGVG6AMKpaAVxYMQAdlIOAMngMmABy7gBGmMQSAGykAA6oCoS2DM5uHt7xickCAUGhLBFRXLGWmNYpQgRMxARp7p4%2BZRUCVTUEeSHhkTEW1bX1GU39HYFdhT0lAJQWqK7EyOwcAKQATADMgchuWADUy%2BuOCgT4ggB0CAfYyxoAggD092vrccRMwCxMu3FMyADWuwgcVcCgQpC4UxutwIAE84pgsFRdrtjsRXNZ9ndTEwCARiHgwq4CJhTFAfv8EVMpsjHrttoZgLsBLQYbsAO41BgKdmEBC7HF4gnE3YMVAEb5vD5MKG7YnHYwKKHLLwAIRlyN2rkCBGikmM4qYXAOaruGs12t1%2Bv5q2N6uRWsEloN61tpo1Dp1eoNkldtzNHqd/IArL7/RavfzoqH3eGrUwvNH7dqABxWsJG9Ymv0ax7GaGoFh4ZB2pOOiNMZO%2B5UAETlBF9j2er3en2%2BvwBQNQcUhdyhedoeGAzAUEF11Lru2AtFQYTE%2Bqrd21u0%2BgQgPduyqzZon9czJexRELyAVRGIJIYEDW0QgBDOFZmuy4pF2pluABUAPIAWQAko5jAAStgfi3AAGtg1aQnubrImeBDzAwL7GDiBZFsYeAKMY07/MYVBnpgEDJs%2BV7QNOs60Pqd7JlSVZeNWSq9oxtxLscJAknWN6YMcuwAFQEOum77shh5oZgqjIAgDLnpeqzXgQAC0Vz3s%2BT5Ie%2B35/oBwFgRBUFZiWcEIUhKFHuhmHYX8uH4YRxGyQpSnUbR9FMVCS7Tkw6D6lxBCcdxfECaqJaPIZxCIfZ6zYBWia7CFiEHqhx7uZ5F4keFkXUc%2Br6fr%2B/5ASB4GQU5HAzLQnBBrwngcFopCoJwjgonMCyYPsGw8KQBCaMVMx/CA6xeGc0QlFwyZ9Ro0QAJySOsE36JwkgVZ1NWcLwCggBo7WdTMcCwDAUC7RASBoCwcR0JE5CUEdJ30FEyD0kYJQaOtWAAG5FpgABqeCYGyH7wpVbU0LQxLEKtEBhItYSBDUMKcG1kPMMQMIfmE2jlB13C8EdbCCB%2BDAsotWCfEY4hVbw%2BBnhUz1cYtYnlESSxtdqmClaT%2BgEm8iPOFgsO8IKLA8zMVAGMACifd9v2MDzMiCCIYjsFI0vyEoaiLboT4GEYICmMY5gDmEq2QDMXY2AIq0cPJH6rLs8kAOpiLQ1s22JeJMCtzNoyk9gME4LgNHo/hjAURR6AkSQm6kvsZE%2Boc5AwnRB5MFjuy0DBtAMkeeE%2BzTh2noz5N0xR9O0gyZ0XtTxwXEgzAojWLHoHI43EBA/gw/AC7NHDlaQlXVbVHC7KoybRPJup0hrjIlGcGhT4CuCECQLXrBCvObTMCCYB5PRrqQPXrOsZx74fR/H7ELPzaQ/NBpIB%2BSJI42rBoe/jYfXjSD3vB9yta0baTW37YdBYrpnQoBAS6p0brAC4KsVYpAXpvTFj9P6UtAbA1BuDVm8NoZS0wYjZGqNrBSyxowAguN8as0JgyEm1VyYeypmbaqtNkD0ylkzFm1U9YcxhFzBmvN8T8wxoLYWosvqIMlhjRWstxAK34IIRQKh1Cs10DA8eWszBs31vAI2TcUhmwtlbW29tHbOzeG7Kw4cvY%2B3SKXAO%2BcJiFxjuHEuIdsjhwrnYvQ2dKgjCcVnZOOcRhuODlnbxGcPEBMDpXCEsx5h1yfA3EhTcW5twER3Lu78lr90HsPUewBbqPlWGcK2EA56nkXsvH%2BWgqSkHXpvKI28eqSAKdELwfU7632iNEIMXhkzqzmgtVmn8LDf3RpU0g21EAgDmAQYEBBzqgMAeA4IrAlhZJHpISceSoGFN4Aiee%2BJ0B6BkcIUQUjpBHLkSrRRIAYFsjeHEduLM0mLT7h%2BIkMymRIlWTkzZBSinOGOuAxeqwpgr1/t1a5%2B9xr33GlwLw0DHoaGTMmIMyi%2Bnd2ectIZ60RldQ7qsXgl9xpnChSS0lpKh7ooGZinFf94AHUmW8okcywHXSWWwTgXz1l3QntEKeU8dn4FPHgA5T4jmSPlmc2QFyFHVTVqQW5TB7kpMef03unBXnTKJB8geQ81ljwZI%2BXl08NCAn%2BUA4gZSQUVNxTUrAdSSpov5pIda6TBmrWxavHeIBogFPWCNHpPrn4aCDNEPeHd1iqo/tSz1LN8WUrVRwUFlSZhUxBp7SQQA%3D%3D))

```
<source>:41:30: warning: taking address of packed member 'a8' of class or structure 'test_s' may result in an unaligned pointer value [-Waddress-of-packed-member]
    return __atomic_load_n(&(t->a8), __ATOMIC_RELAXED);
                             ^~~~~
<source>:41:12: warning: misaligned atomic operation may incur significant performance penalty; the expected alignment (8 bytes) exceeds the actual alignment (1 bytes) [-Watomic-alignment]
    return __atomic_load_n(&(t->a8), __ATOMIC_RELAXED);
```

The `__atomic_store_8` library function clang calls will actually give atomicity on x86-64; it ignores the memory_order parameter in RDX and assumes `__ATOMIC_SEQ_CST` - the implementation is just `xchg [rdi],rsi` / `ret`.

But `__atomic_load_8` won't: its implementation is `mov rax, [rdi]` / `ret` (because [C++ atomic mappings to x86 asm](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Epes20/cpp/cpp0xmappings.html) put the cost of blocking StoreLoad reordering between seq_cst ops onto stores, leaving SC loads the same as acquire.)  So clang isn't gaining anything by choosing not to inline `__atomic_load_n` for a known-misaligned 8-byte load.

OTOH it doesn't hurt, and a custom implementation of libatomic could do something about it, e.g. with `lock cmpxchg`, or whatever else if you're running in some emulator or other weird environment.

Interesting that clang chooses not to inline based on misalignment.  But its warning only makes sense for atomic RMW ops on x86-64, where it is a performance penalty rather than lack of atomicity.  Or SC stores, as long as libatomic implements that with `xchg` rather than `mov` + `mfence`.

Comment: "This isn't explicitly documented in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html but perhaps is somewhere else." I was also looking at this documentation, then at GCC-generated machine code for different `__atomic_*` were used in it, and I was scratching my head. Why didn't they mention the alignment requirements in any way?

Comment: @GrigoryRechistov: I had a look at the GCC wiki, https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/C11 mentions alignment somewhat.  https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic doesn't but links a bunch of other stuff.

Comment: @GrigoryRechistov: I just realized `_Alignof(_Atomic T)` should work as an equivalent to C++ `alignof(std::atomic<T>)` for any lock-free atomic type, which is the same as `std::atomic_ref<T>::required_alignment` on any GNU system.